# Fluent API Many to Many Mapping Error

Tags: orm, entity-framework-4, mapping, fluent-interface

I have the following mapping to support a many to many table (User_Role)

```
     modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
        .HasMany<User>(u => u.users)
        .WithMany(r => r.roles)
        .Map(m => 
           m.MapLeftKey("role_id")
           m.MapRightKey("user_id")
           m.ToTable("User_Role"));
```

This works great from mapping many roles to a user and many users to a role. The problem I am having is when I need to add a new row to the table User_Role via an entity as follows:

```
public class User_Role
{
   [Key Column(Order=1)]   
   public int role_id {get;set;)
   [Key Column(Order=1)]
   public int user_id {get;set;)
}
```

Whenever I try to access this entity as follows:

```
 dbContext.User_Role.Add(new User_Role {user_id ....
```

EF looks for a non existent table called User_Role1 ... its adding a '1' to the table name.

I then tried to add:

```
  [Table("User_Role")]
```

This takes care of the adding a '1' but I now get this error:

"The EntitySet 'RoleUser' with schema 'dbo' and table 'User_Role' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to a unique schema and table"

I was able to confirm that the following lines together are causing the problem but I kind of need them both

```
 m.ToTable("User_Role") and public class User_Role..
```

Any suggestions would be great...I am stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot represent the join table in a many-to-many relationship by an entity class in your model. This join table is managed by EF and you cannot directly access this table. If you want to create a relationship between an existing user and an existing role you must do this using these two entities:

```cs
var user = dbContext.Users.Single(u => u.id == user_id);
var role = dbContext.Roles.Single(r => r.id == role_id);

// if you don't have lazy loading and don't instantiate the collection
// in the constructor, add this: user.roles = new List<Role>(); 

user.roles.Add(role);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This will write an entry for the new relationship (the (user_id,role_id) pair) into the join table.

**Edit**

If you only have the two key properties at hand and don't want to load the user and role from the database you can work with attached "stub entities":

```cs
var user = new User { id = user_id, roles = new List<Role>() };
var role = new Role { id = role_id };

dbContext.Users.Attach(user);
dbContext.Roles.Attach(role);

user.roles.Add(role);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```